# Convertir string de localstorage a tipos de datos manejables en JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy haciendo un administrador de dinero con React, ya está finalizado, ahora lo que quiero es actualizarlo, me explico: el administrador no trabaja con bases de datos, por lo que al recargar la página se pierde todo, ahora trato de almacenar las cosas en el almacenamiento local.

### Problema:

En mis states guardo la información del presupuesto, los gastos, etc., ahora lo malo es que en el almacenamiento, los datos solo son guardados en string, mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para transformar ese string y poder manejarlo con js? Por ejemplo, con el presupuesto y el restante es tan simple como un `parseInt` o `parseFloat`, pero también tengo un arreglo de la lista de gastos, ese es el complicado.

Código de los states:

```
const [presupuesto, guardarPresuesto]       = useState(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto') === '0' ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto'))),
      [restante, guardarRestante]           = useState(localStorage.getItem('restante') === '0' ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem('restante'))),
      [mostrarpregunta, actualizarPregunta] = useState(localStorage.getItem('showQuestion') === 'true' ? true : false),
      [gastos, guardarGastos]               = useState(localStorage.getItem('gastos') === '[]' ? [] : localStorage.getItem('gastos')), //este es el del problema :c
```

No tengo ni idea, pero diría que se podría hacer con `JSON.parse` asi como cuando se trabaja con ajax (?... no sé la verdad, por eso escribo por aquí a ver si alguno me dice ;D

Felíz resto de día programadores :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto compañero, puedes hacer uso de [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) para tratar arrays, números, incluso objetos. Cuando se trate de cadenas de texto pues no tiene caso hacer uso del parseo pues ya es una cadena de texto. Así que dependiendo de tu lógica, sabrás cuándo utilizar o no el método `JSON.parse`.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('[0, 1, 5, 9]'));

console.log(JSON.parse('true'));

console.log(JSON.parse('1'))

console.log(JSON.parse('[0, [6, true], 9, {"objeto": false, "o": null}]'));
```

Así que en tu código tendrías also similar a lo siguiente:

```
const [presupuesto, guardarPresuesto]       = useState(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto') === '0' ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem('presupuesto'))),
      [restante, guardarRestante]           = useState(localStorage.getItem('restante') === '0' ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem('restante'))),
      [mostrarpregunta, actualizarPregunta] = useState(localStorage.getItem('showQuestion') === 'true' ? true : false),
      [gastos, guardarGastos]               = useState(localStorage.getItem('gastos') === '[]' ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gastos'))),
```